# How can I maintain a log file efficiently?

Tags: c#, logging

Currently I have a `.txt` file that has the time that an "select" in a database took to execute, when it was executed and how many rows it retrieve. What I want to do is delete the logs generated older than x date.

Code that is appending to .txt:

```
public void LogSQL(string rowsSQL, float timeSQL, string stringSQL)
{
    System.IO.StreamWriter sw = System.IO.File.AppendText(pathTxt() + "LogsSQL.txt");

    try
    {
        string x = System.String.Format("{0} - SQL STATEMENT: {1}{2} Number of Rows: {3}{4} Process Time: {5} seconds {6}--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------", System.DateTime.Now, stringSQL, Environment.NewLine, rowsSQL, Environment.NewLine, timeSQL, Environment.NewLine);
        sw.WriteLine(x);
    }
    finally
    {
        sw.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have log files that are date stamped.  So you should never have a log file that has more than one date in it

Comment: Have a look at log4net.

Comment: The complexity in having to tackle deleting lines within the log based on the date for each line, is just a headache involved. Why are you not using log4net or NLog?

Comment: Or Serilog? It sounds like you want a rolling log file which is a solved problem I would argue you shouldn't try to do yourself.

Comment: All these suggestions about using already written libraries probably don't take in consideration that changing an already deployed log infrastructure is not an easy task. Have you ever tried to change something like that  on a hundred thousands lines application?

Comment: @Steve shouldn't the logger always be written against an abstraction?  If the current log solution OP has does not have an abstraction behind it, they have bigger problems...

Comment: Those are problems very common in older applications. It seems that there are no such abstractions here.

Comment: Thank you to everyone for the answer. As a begginer on programming, i thought that it would be easier to solve my problem with code instead of using a librarie, but it looks like i was wrong. I have decided to study log4net, any suggestions on where to begin?

Comment: I wouldn't use log4net. [Serilog](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file) and [NLog](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/File-target) are much better documented. They have plenty of information for you to get started on rolling file logging.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way out from this. The only possible solution is to copy the log file with a temporary name, open it and parse each line to find the datestamp. If the date is older then a certain cutoff discard the line else write in another temporary file. When done copy the new file overwriting the current one (of course the scenario is a lot more complicated if you have many threads writing to the same file)

However I would suggest you a simple change to your actual code that allows you to write your log in different files whose name is based on the current date.

```
public void LogSQL(string rowsSQL, float timeSQL, string stringSQL)
{
    string logFile = Path.Combine(pathTxt(), $"LogsSQL-{DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd"}).txt")
    using(System.IO.StreamWriter sw = System.IO.File.AppendText(logFile))
    {
        string x = System.String.Format(.......);
        sw.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

In this way you write all the day's logs in the same file, and the next day in another file. At this point removing the log before a certain date it is just a matter of deleting the matching files

```
public void RemoveLogs(DateTime cutOff)
{
    foreach (string s in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"e:\temp"))
    {
        int pos = s.LastIndexOf("-");
        if (pos != -1)
        {
            if (pos + 9 < s.Length)
            {
                string date = s.Substring(pos + 1, 8);
                if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dateFile))
                {
                    if(dateFile < cutOff)
                        File.Delete(s);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```